# How can I define my metrics for test on django?

Tags: python, django, testing, automated-tests, code-coverage

I need to define some metrics for my tests in my application. So I need to my application only deploy if the minimum for my code coverage was 50%, like I defined. So if my tests doesn't pass, my deploy will stop (I use Travis CI for my automation deployment)

I use Django for my tests. It's possible?